# ReactJS: jQuery like components built with Flux

Tags: jquery, facebook, components, reactjs, flux

Scenario: I want to extend an existing React component and deliver it as a standalone component.

Let's take for example Facebook's `FixedDataTable` (https://github.com/facebook/fixed-data-table), add some extra features and wrap it as a re-usable component.

The first extra feature would be "multiple row selection" - demo can be found here http://goo.gl/qRE9eB

What anyone can notice here is that the `MovieTable` wrapper handles the checked / not checked state of the rows. So, what I'll want to do next is to delegate the responsibility of the state handling to a Flux store (for simplicity, let's consider Facebook Flux implementation https://github.com/facebook/flux). Probably it doesn't make too much sense to do this now, but as the complexity of the `MovieTable` grows (sorting, infinite scrolling etc.), integrating Flux would be a necessity. According to Flux architecture (Action -> Dispatcher -> Store -> View), `_onRowClick` and `_onCheckAll` will trigger actions which will allow the Store to save the state and notify the view that something was changed, in order for the view to re-render the new state of the checkbox.

Let's assume next that I want to bundle the `MovieTable` view together with its actions / dispatcher / store as a standalone component, so that I could re-use it later. First question:

1) does it make sense to bundle together the view / actions / dispatcher / store as a standalone component? From my point of view, the benefits are clear: the one that uses the component doesn't need to take care of the "internals" of the component (e.g. row selection, infinite scrolling, sorting etc.)

Let's consider that I choose to bundle everything together. The next questions are:

2) How can I get data out of the Store? e.g. some part of the application might need to get all the selected rows from the component's Store

3) How can I trigger actions on the dispatcher of the component? e.g. I want to programmatically check some rows - my first thought is that the client should have access to the actions of the component

4) Given 1), 2) and 3), I want to have a re-usable DataTable component that "feels" like a traditional jQuery component (e.g. jqGrid http://goo.gl/b7jPo3). The ultimate goal would be to combine jQuery like components with React components in the same page, without causing too much pain to the one that mixes these.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's fine to *implement* complex libraries with flux (or any other design pattern) under the hood, but that the library should make every effort to hide these complexities from the end-user. For example, a Node.js library might use callbacks, an [async control flow library](https://github.com/caolan/async), or promises to manage asynchronous operations inside the library itself, but to allow users to interop with most Node apps, it should at least support callbacks in the public API. (As promises become more first-class in JavaScript, this pattern may shift, but I hope you get my point.)

In React, the least-common-denominator for component-based APIs are props (to provide data, and to provide function references to serve as callbacks). If at all possible, attempt to make your API work using just props.

If, in a very large or complex component, that's just not possible (and I would argue that the component+props strategy [can take you a *very* long way](https://github.com/rackt/react-router) before it really breaks down), it may make sense to expose a more traditional, object/method-based API. However, I would still strive not to expose the flux underpinnings—a [facade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) with a method called `dataTable.selectRows(rowIndicies)` (which delegates to the actions) is easier to understand/remember and is less brittle/resistant to change than `dataTable.dispatcher.dispatch(DataTableActions.selectRows(rowIndicies))`.

---

I'm not quite sure I understand the #4 item (maybe it's not really a question?) If I'm already building a React app, I have no desire to expose React components as jQuery plugins, if I'm building a non-React, jQuery app, I don't really have a desire to require React as a dependency just to use a data table.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!
To recap what the public API should look at a minimum for a React component:
a) props or methods as setters (e.g. `<myComponent ref="myComponent" filtersProp={[{...},{...}]}` or `this.refs.myComponent.setFilters([{...},{...}]) />`
b) props or methods as callbacks (e.g. `<myComponent ref="myComponent" onGetData={function () {...}}` or `this.refs.myComponent.setOnGetData(function () {...})`)
c) methods as getters (e.g. `this.refs.myComponent.getFilters()`)

Comment: Since c) can't really be debatable as there is a single way to expose getters, I would take a look at a) and b).
Let's see what advantages offers the "props" way of providing data (includes callbacks also):
- integrates well with components' lifecycle: `propTypes`, `getDefaultProps()`, `componentWillReceiveProps ()` etc.
- it's easy to remember how to interact with the component: no need to think which behavior of the component must be specified as a prop and which as a method

Comment: - given the fact that a component re-renders itself each time something changed, I would think that this looks more like calling a constructor every time, rather than calling a constructor just once and then calling setters for every change that needs to be reflected
I don't see any disadvantages with "props" - if you could share a few, it would be great.

Comment: Indeed, #4 is not a question, but rather a scenario that relates to consuming the components. However, let me give you more details on it: I have a jQuery app and I want to "sprinkle" this and there different React components from a library - let's call it MyReactLibrary. In order to render them, I need to include React in my jQuery app, since MyReactLibrary is having "React" marked as "external" because from MyReactLibrary's perspective, there's a good chance that the consumer is using React also.

Comment: Otherwise, MyReactLibrary would have to expose a sort of wrapper that would allow me to consume components without having to require React. But then, what if my jQuery app suddenly needs to use React also? Do you have an example of a React component that can be used in a non-React, jQuery app, without requiring React as a dependency and without forcing you to use it in strictly non-React environment?